# Justifying the trend component in a time series?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

I am working on a time series forecasting problem ,I used Dickey–Fuller test to check the stationary of the time series and the p value is 0.000835 , hense I rejected the null hypothesis and assumed that it's a stationary time series.

I decomposed the time series and the trend component does not have any particular pattern.plot-[image]

I want to ask how can we justify that a time series has any particular trend, **Is this decomposition enough to ensure and guarantee that this time series has no trend** ?

Plot of rolling mean-

[image]

Plot of rolling variance-

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Augmented Dickey–Fuller test is **UNIT ROOT** test - **NOT** a stationarity test. The null-hypothesis on this test is that the data have been generated by a restricted AR model containing a unit-root. Rejecting this hypothesis DOES NOT mean the series is stationary. It just means that there is enough evidence to allow you rejecting the hypothesis of a very specific form of NON-stationarity (i.e. unit root). Evidence is assessed contrastively i.e. v.s. an unrestricted AR model. Rejecting the hypothesis that an animal is a chicken with an alternative being a pig doesn't mean the animal might not be a horse! The examined animal might **contrastively** not look like a chicken (e.g. because it has 4 legs) but that doesn't make it a pig.

Now look at your decomposition. You could see with a bare eye **data don't look stationary**. Trend as well as variance change with time. The decomposition does not support your conclusion. It supports the opposite view. There both parametric as well as non-parametric ways to check changes in the trend of the series. For example  (see following poster about [Detecting Changes in the Mean](https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/media/lancaster-university/content-assets/documents/stor-i/interns-docs/NicolaHuxley_POSTER(2).pdf) ):

[image: test]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding the Dickey–Fuller test.I have added the plots of rolling mean and variance of the time series with a window of 10.It's observed that the variance is almost constant with some fluctuations while the mean has many change points. I am using R package changepoint to detect the change points ,but I want to ask is there any method to forecast the future change points/ give a probability to the future points that they may be change  points.

Answer (score 2):

visually there is an apparent autoregressive process and a change in model error variance .. thus non-stationarity is the call.